# how to auto increment a number with file handling

Tags: c

```
            printf("\nID #: %d",counter++);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEnter Menu Name: ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s",&menus.name);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter what the menu made of (pork,beef,chicken): ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%[^\n]s",&menus.make);
            printf("Number of Servings: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d",&menus.numserve);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Price: ");
            scanf("%f",&menus.price);
            fflush(stdin);
            fwrite(&menus, 1, sizeof(menus), fp);
            numofentrees--;
```

my problem is I want to auto generate my ID# so i incremented it, then I want my file handling to read the last number for example I wish to input 2 records then my ID number should generate 1 and 2 then after i fill up the records I wish to generate a record again then my next ID number should be 3 but in my program it would return ID#1 again. can someone explain it to me thanks. i'm using C language

Comment: Don't do `fflush(stdin)`, it's an undefined operation to call `fflush` on input-only streams.

Comment: And if you want to read full lines, use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: As for your problem, where is `counter` defined? Where and how is it initialized or assigned to? Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: When using `scanf` with the `%s` format you should not have a `&` in front of the variable passed as argument.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vvxkxusC 

here is my actual program at the moment

Comment: In your pastebin the line `int counter=1;` defines a local variable, whose lifetime is only during the function call. At the next call, it is again initialised to `1`. You could define it as `static int counter = 1;` But apart from that, the code looks as if it was translated from BASIC with all those `goto` statements. In a C program they should only be used as a last resort to make a dirty jump from the program's flow control logic, if at all.

Comment: yea i'm still new to programming , anyway thanks guys :D

Comment: Offsite links die. All of your code must be in the question, and you should minimize it so that only what's needed to reproduce the problem is left.

Comment: yea my problem is when i try to view my list in the file handling the id# is only #1 that's why i want it to increment so basically I want to see in my file handling in each record the id# should be incremented

Comment: here's my new code (i'm new to programming) http://pastebin.com/WmPh2234

Answer (score 0):

In your pastebin the line `int counter=1;` defines a local variable, whose lifetime is only during the function call. At the next call, it is again initialised to `1`. You could define it as `static int counter = 1;` …
                    – Weather Vane